# Sftp aborting at passphrase prompt when running from C#

Tags: c#, batch-file, cmd, sftp, winscp

I have a batchfile that runs sftp command and works fine if I double click it from 
 folder, but when I execute the batch file from my C# code I get an error saying 
 "User aborted at passphrase prompt".

Here is my C# code that executes the batch file:

```
Process proc = new Process();

proc.StartInfo.FileName  = BatchFile + ".bat";
                        
proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow   = true;
proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = _tpDir;
proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

try
{
   proc.Start();
   proc.WaitForExit();
   proc.Close();
}
```

Here is my batch file code in batch file **RcvEdi.bat** which calls **RcvEdi.txt**:

```
WinSCP.exe /log="WinRecv.log" /ini=nul /script="RcvEdi.txt"
```

This is the code in **RcvEdi.txt**:

```
open sftp://USERID@somesite.com/ -hostkey="ssh-rsa 2048 uAHzHhxcIEZu4cX3HbYlsIohejeZVQ1siT0oDihpP3g=" -privatekey="C:\folder\amichryprivatekey.ppk"

cd Outbox
mget *
exit
```

Now this works if I just double click the **RcvEdi.bat** file or 
if I login from WinSCP.exe.

Here is the error in my error log report:

```
Offered public key
. 2021-11-10 12:11:04.810 Offer of public key accepted
! 2021-11-10 12:11:04.810 Authenticating with public key "rsa-key-20211005"
< 2021-11-10 12:11:04.810 Script: Authenticating with public key "rsa-key-20211005".
. 2021-11-10 12:11:04.810 Prompt (passphrase, "SSH key passphrase", <no instructions>, "Passphrase for key "rsa-key-20211005": ")
. 2021-11-10 12:11:04.811 User aborted at passphrase prompt
. 2021-11-10 12:11:04.811 Attempt to close connection due to fatal exception:
* 2021-11-10 12:11:04.811 **Connection has been unexpectedly closed.** Server sent command exit status 0.
. 2021-11-10 12:11:04.811 Closing connection.
```

Any help would be appreciated!!!

Comment: Are you running your application in the same environment in which you run the batch file manually? + Post complete WinSCP logs + Post WinSCP log from manual run too.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Yes same environment.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl yes logs also.

Comment: You didn't post any logs.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I posted the error above that is displayed in the log report. Is that what you're referring to?

Comment: I have asked for *"**complete** WinSCP logs + Post WinSCP **log from manual run** too"*. You have posted one log snippet only.